# How to Debug Linux Kernel using GDB in qemu environment

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb

I have requirement where i wanted to debud my Linux kernel image using GDB but not sure whats is option available for it,

When I run below command

gdb ./vmlinux

```
 users/amit/vmlinuz-2.6.32-33-generic": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `z` at the end of `vmlinuz` tells you that your kernel image is in a compressed format. To debug it, you need to have an uncompressed version. You *can* extract a `vmlinux` from your `vmlinuz`, but you have to make sure you have the required debug symbols somewhere (System.map?).

The easiest option is probably to rebuild your kernel with debug symbols and without compression.